Resetting Dropdown State on DOM Changes in a Chrome Extension
I'm developing a Chrome Extension that includes a dropdown menu and a button. The dropdown's visibility and the button's functionality depend on specific values detected within the page's CSS selectors.
Problem: I need the dropdown menu to reset to its default state (null for no selection) when specific HTML elements on the page change. These changes typically occur when a user interacts with elements that update the content in a right pane.
While the dropdown does reset under certain conditions (for example if the dropdown is disabled and then enabled again), it does not reset when the content in the right pane changes. The method I'm using feels somewhat forced and may not be responsive enough given the dynamic nature of the content changes.
Current Approach: Here is how the dropdown is initialized and managed
// Function to handle dropdown selection
const handleDropdownSelect = (option) => {
  setSelectedOption(option);
};

// Polling function to detect changes and manage the dropdown visibility and button data
const pollForElements = useCallback(async () => {
  let attempts = 0;
  const maxAttempts = 120;

  while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
    const rightPaneContent = document.querySelector('#right-pane-content');
    if (rightPaneContent) {
      const switchElement = rightPaneContent.querySelector('[selector-for-condition]');
      const showDropdown = switchElement?.textContent?.includes('specific-text') ?? false;

      setShowDropdown(showDropdown);
      if (!showDropdown) {
        setSelectedOption(null);  // Resetting the dropdown
      }

      // Other logic to update the button text based on content
      // ...
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 250));
    attempts++;
  }
  return { heading: "", body: "" };
}, []);


Code for Button and Dropdown in the Component:
// React component rendering the dropdown and button
return (
  <div className="plasmo-fixed-right-panel">
    {showDropdown && (
      <DropdownMenu
        options={['Option 1', 'Option 2']}
        onSelect={handleDropdownSelect}
        selectedOption={selectedOption}
      />
    )}
    <ExportButton disabled={!selectedOption} onClick={handleExport} />
  </div>
);


I also tried an implementation of MutationObserver, but wasn't able to figure out how to implement it specifically to this use case.
